# Error when Deactivating Farm Feature - Failed to load receiver assembly

Tags: feature-activation, sharepoint-on-prem, farm-solution, feature-receiver

I have a farm feature that was updated by PowerShell with the following:

```
Update-SPSolution -Identity FILE.wsp -LiteralPath "PATH\TO\FILE.wsp" –GACDeployment
```

I'm trying to deactivate and then reactivate the Farm Feature and I'm receiving the error copied below. The funny thing is the registry key it's referencing doesn't exist.

```
[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]
```

> Error 
>   Failed to load receiver assembly "Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.ClientExtensions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" for feature "DMS.Bcs.DmsDataService_DataServiceBCS" (ID: 8cf15518-ba61-49c1-846c-5812a3227157).: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.ClientExtensions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
>   File name: 'Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.ClientExtensions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' 
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection) 
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) 
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) 
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) 
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject()
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. 
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. 
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. 
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: 15219ac9-9552-4224-a8aa-fb3dc6cf12a9
>
> Date and Time: 4/24/2017 2:19:52 PM

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the `Microsoft.Office.SharePoint.ClientExtensions` dll to GAC.

Here is one similar thread for your reference.
http://www.sharepoint4developers.net/en-nz/post/add-solution-failed-to-load-receiver-assembly.aspx

Comment: "Register the DLLs in the GAC to fix it, just copying them to the directory C:\Windows\assembly." - This does not work. I am getting Access Denied when trying to copy DLL to that folder.